# Why don't Logitech keyboards' media keys work?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard-shortcuts

I get weird behavior with Windows 8, on several computers (HP and Dell laptops, and a tower PC) with different Logitech keyboards (K800, G15, and G510): right after the Windows installation, everything works fine. But after the first batch of updates, the media keys (sound +/-, backward/forward, play/pause) donn't work anymore.

Note that I've never installed any driver for my Logitech hardware (and everything has always worked fine so far). I performed the test with the tower PC and the K800 keyboard, but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Solution found on this Logitech forum's thread: [G510, Media Keys and Windows 8](http://forums.logitech.com/t5/G-Series-Gaming-Keyboards/G510-Media-Keys-and-Windows-8/m-p/944792/highlight/true#M26630)

It looks like one of the first updates messes up the HID (Human Interface Device) service activation.  In order to fix it, follow these steps:

1. Press Windows+X and select "Computer management".
2. At the left, under "computer management", you find "Services and Applications". Open it and select "Services".
3. Search for a service named *Human Interface Device Access* (or something VERY similiar).
4. Once found, check the status. If the value is not "Started", start it.
5. To make sure it will be on also in the future, check the Startup Type value. If not "Automatic", right click it, and select properties.
6. Under the tab "General", change the Startup type to Automatic.
7. Apply and close.

[image]

Comment: Works for other keyboards and media remotes! Thanks

Comment: I tried this, but it only works when the Services windows is the selected window, or when one of two others are (Gigabyte Force, Curse Voice). Any thoughts?

Comment: For everyone using a German version of Windows: The Service is called "Zugriff auf Eingabegeräte", so don't try to find it under "Eingabegeräte" or "Human Interface Device" where you'd expect it. It's hiding right down at the bottom of the list.

Comment: @DarkWolffe did you solve the problem?

Comment: @latata in my case the problem was the Google Play Music plugin for Google Chrome. It overrides the media keys in a really funny way.

Comment: @DarkWolffe thanks a lot! I turned off Google Play Music plugin and  now it works!

Comment: I had the same problem with K800 as the OP (under Windows 10), though the initial startup type was set to manual, the HID service was running but the buttons were not working. After setting the startup type to automatic, it worked after a restart.

Comment: In french, the service is called "Service du périphérique d'interface utilisateur". But it doesn't work well in my case ...

Comment: @DarkWolffe Genius!!

Comment: @Cora: please make this an answer and take my upvote. it's ridiculous that this was the issue in my case @_@ (Windows 10)

Answer (score 0):

@Anto's answer didn't work for me on Windows 10 iTunes 12 but this did:

http://andy.hillhome.org/blog/code/ituneskeys/